# How to sort the collection by two keys? c# IEnumerable thenby not working while sorting collection by startdate

Tags: c#

I have a scenario where collection contains startdate and enddate. I want to sort it by end date. Also if two or more items having same end date then it should be ordered by startdate. So for this I written a linq query like below but thenby clause is not working for me.Also I want to know how can I compare two items enddate and sortdate and sort the collection?

```
var activeAuctions = auctions
  .Where(auction => auction.Status.Equals(Consts.AuctionStatus.Past, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == false)
  .OrderBy(auction => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(auction.EndDate) ? auction.EndDate : auction.StartDate)
  .ThenBy(auction => auction.StartDate);
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is there some error? Are the values not sorted correctly? If so, how are they sorted? What sorting are you expecting?

Comment: Where do you want the items without an end date to appear? At the beginning or at the end? Are your dates strings? How are they formatted?

Comment: `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(auction.EndDate) ` <-- **Argh** _don't use `String` to represent date/datetime values_ 

Comment: Just do `.OrderBy(auction => auction.EndDate).ThenBy(acution => auction.StartDate)` and change your column type to `date` or `datetime`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var activeAuctions = auctions
  .Where(auction => auction.Status.Equals(Consts.AuctionStatus.Past, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == false)
  .ToList()
  .OrderBy(auction => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(auction.EndDate) ? auction.EndDate : auction.StartDate)
  .ThenBy(auction => auction.StartDate);
```

ToList() executes the query immediatelly and returns you a List of results. Therefore, in the second line, there is a second, independent query that takes the List of the previous results to order.

Comment: This won't solve the OP's problem. Their results are in the wrong output order because they're sorting by **String** representations of date/time values, which will always give you gibberish output ordering (_unless_ they're using ISO 8601, which I highly doubt...).

Comment: It would be really helpful if you included a brief description of what was wrong and how you changed the code to solve it - i.e. why would adding `ToList()` before the `OrderBy` clauses improve the results?

Comment: might work if the issue was that the linq2 framework was failing to correctly interpret the sort into the base data source however sorting in a pretty standard thing to implement in any linq2 frameowrk so would have to be a really dodgy source for that to be the issue

Comment: I gave one answer to one undifined question. As far as I can see, with the provided info, the problem may be there. I understand the down vote (dont agree with it). I was just trying to open @Swarel Jadhav options to resolve his issue dispite the already given suitable responses. Cheers all.